# Can I melt my thirumangalyam and can i get done newly

Tags: women

Can someone confirm if can I melt my thali and get it done newly with same gold.

Comment: what is thiru mangalyam that you want to melt?

Comment: Gold Mangalsutra ... Welcome Unfortunately this question is not directly related to this site i.e. Hinduism . But surely you can ask any different question regarding thirumangalyam.

Comment: BTW in general the gold will remain the same as well as the feelings associated with it , only it will change shape. In hinduism scriptures we often find this example.:-)

Comment: Depends on why you want it in new form. If a new design is wished for whatever reason the old material can be melted some extra gold added or removed or remodeled, and  worn on you by the pathidev preferably after elderly blessing.